# Are there any NP-hard problems for which the following statement is true:

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, np

$\overline{A} \le A\ and $ $A \le \overline{A}$

Is the following proof correct?

If $\overline{A} \le A \Rightarrow \overline{A} \in NP$ since A is NP-hard $ \Rightarrow A \in coNP$

Since $\overline{A} \le A$ and $A \in coNP \Rightarrow \overline{A} \in coNP \Rightarrow A \in NP$

$A \in coNP$ and $A \in NP$ iff $NP=coNP$

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing NP and NP-hard in a couple places. For example, let $A$ be the problem of [deciding ATL*](http://www.avacs.org/fileadmin/Publikationen/Open/schewe.icalp08.pdf), which is 2EXPTIME-complete. $A$ is NP-hard and polynomial-time many-one reduces to its complement, but is neither in NP nor in co-NP by the time hierarchy theorem.

---

Recall that an NP-complete problem is one that is in NP and is NP-hard. For every NP-complete problem $A$, we have that $A$ is in co-NP if and only if NP = co-NP. Make sure you understand why: try proving the if direction (easy) and the only if direction (requires a little more thought). Here is the proof of the only if direction, if you get stuck:

> Suppose there exists an NP-complete problem X that is in co-NP. Since all problems in NP can be reduced to X, it follows that for every problem in NP we can construct a non-deterministic Turing machine that decides its complement in polynomial time, i.e., NP ⊆ co-NP. From this it follows that the set of complements of the problems in NP is a subset of the set of complements of the problems in co-NP, i.e., co-NP ⊆ NP. Thus co-NP = NP. [(from Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP)

---

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be any complexity class that is closed under complement and polynomial-time many-one reductions (such as PSPACE, EXPTIME, 2EXPTIME, etc.). Let $P$ be any $\mathbf{C}$-complete problem. Then its complement $\overline{P}$ is also $\mathbf{C}$-complete.

Proof:

> Suppose we are given some problem $Q \in \mathbf{C}$ and we want to reduce it to $\overline{P}$. Since $\mathbf{C}$ is closed under complement, we know that $\overline{Q} \in \mathbf{C}$ as well. Since $P$ is $\mathbf{C}$-complete, there is a reduction $\overline{Q}$ to $P$. But this reduction is *also* a reduction from $Q$ to $\overline{P}$: the accepting and rejecting instances are simply swapped.

Comment: I get your answer. Is there any NP-hard problem then for which the statement above stands and how do I start with proving it if it does (/not) ?

Comment: @Atti Does my edited answer address your question?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm talking about complement(A) <= A and A <= complement(A) one. A might be just NP hard, not NP complete as well.

Comment: @Atti How is that not addressed by my first paragraph? The $A$ I give is an NP-hard problem that polynomial-time many-one reduces to its complement and vice-versa. Or are you using $\le$ to mean something else?

Comment: I don't use it for something else, I just didn't know about the vica-versa part and what the proof for it is based on. Is it true for every 2EXPTIME-complete (or even PSPACE-complete) problem?

Comment: @Atti See my latest edit.